# Не блокировать экран android (Java)

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Здравствуйте!

Я не так давно пишу под андроид и это просто "ради развития". Но появилась такая задача:
**во время работы приложения не должен гаснуть экран**.

Как это можно реализовать? Android 4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для этого нужно использовать класс **PowerManager.WakeLock**

Пример кода есть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5712936/1233682)

Еще, как указали выше, можно добавить пермишн в манифест

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

И 3 вариант: для Активности, которая является главной в твоем приложении, можно задать:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_flag);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
}
```

Comment: мне такой вариант не подходит. вот пример моего файла - http://joxi.ru/n2Yx7EDCoDWgBm

Answer (score 3):

Если вы хотите что бы во время работы всего приложения экран не блокировался то пропишите в манифесте:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Если вы хотите что бы не блокировался только определенный экран, а на всех остальных блокировался то пропишите в нужном вам layout строку

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

или в нужной activity в методе onCreate

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно xml файл в корень или какой-нибудь виджет прописать строчку:

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

Comment: А чего минусовать? Хоть реализовали бы сначала

Answer (score 1):

Надо добавить право в манифест

[android.permission.WAKE_LOCK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)